# Get max-score of Elasticsearch in CakePHP 3

Tags: elasticsearch, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to integrate Elasticsearch with CakePHP, and i couldn't figure out how to get the `max-score` like in json response:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.032739405,
    "hits": [....]
}
```

The query in my controller works as expected, i know that there must be a way to get the max score after the query.

```php
 $this->loadModel("Articles", 'Elastic');
 $articles = $this->Articles->find();
 $articles->where(function ($builder) {
   return $builder->query([
     'match_phrase'=>[
       'title'=>$this->getValue('query')
     ]
   ]);
 });
```

Comment: Why don't you pick score from very first item that's brought back? It's going to have highest score.

Comment: I want to access thu score value of each item so i can decide wich one to display.